# Creating a hash table for a fixed known set of values with low space complexity

Tags: hash, hashtable, space-complexity, computation-theory

I'm trying to understand low level optimization better and I'm currently going over hash tables/sets. As the title suggests, I'm trying to find a way to save as much space as possible while still keeping an amortized O(1) time for finding a value in the table. Lets say I know which keys are going to be in the table and how many of them there are (The keys are fixed, no new keys would be added).

**Some Ideas regarding the hashing itself:**

I read about minimal perfect hashing a bit, and through it I got to the idea that I should hash only some of the bits/bytes of the value I'm given (some prefix/postfix as an example) to lower the amount of entries and thus lower the amount of pointers needed for the table (There would be more collisions, but if I find a good amount of bits to hash that might be negligible). Even if it's a good idea, I'm not sure how to pick this amount.

Lets say I chose to use a prefix of size X.
One idea I had regarding the issue mentioned above was to calculate the distribution of the prefixes of the keys, if the distribution is close to uniform - X is a good size for the prefix, otherwise I should look for a different sized prefix (Choose X that gives me the distribution that is closest to uniform but is still smaller than some size).

But again, lets say the distribution is always uniform:
What size of prefix would be ideal?

**My questions in an orderly format:**

1. Generally - how can I save space while still keeping amortized O(1) time for choosing items in the hash table?
2. Specifically - Is my idea to use only a hash of some prefix to get more collisions but lower the generally needed size of the table good?
3. Is there a way to save the data in a more compact (space wise) way? i.e - if the keys are strings, representing them using only some of their chars or grouping multiple chars to get a unique numeral value and use that instead.
   If the keys are numerals so maybe store multiple keys in the same 64bit int, first half of bits representing the first numeral and second half of bits the other?

Any thoughts and directions, reading materials so I can think on my own or direct answers to my question would be appreciated!